# Struts 2 form customization

Tags: forms, struts2, themes

I use Struts 2 to create form in my application. I am struggling with a form customization.
I 've tried with theme simple, xhtml and css_xhtml but i am not able to find a solution.
Struts display the one input text by row, i want to display two or more input text by row. I join the image which explains want i'd like to do.
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to simply accept the layout Struts gives you and by assigning unique id's to your input fields take control the layout through a custom css file.

Comment: Which theme is the simpliest to modify and get my desired result ?

Comment: After many test, i've resolved my problem by using the simple theme. And adding custom css to format my form. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With "simple" theme you can do whatever you want; there's nothing provided other than form value and input element. (You also don't get the automatic error reporting with the form element, but it looks like you wouldn't want that anyway.) If it's not working with "simple" then you're building your form wrong, or forgetting to include your own label, or something.

Answer (score 0):

After many test, i've resolved my problem by using the simple theme. And adding custom css to format my form. Thanks –